# why coloumn not updating using in pl/sql

Tags: oracle10g

i am trying to calculate the cgpa of a student from his term gpa.
and store the gpa value in gpa coloumn in the result table.

my code link:http://paste.ubuntu.com/21677789/.

finally it's showing the output:

```
hello term1

1307001  2  1    2

hello year2

hello term1

1307001  3  1    1.7

hello year3

hello roll1307001

hello term1

1307002  2  1    1.71315789473684210526315789473684210526

hello year2

hello term1

1307002  3  1    1.76315789473684210526315789473684210526

hello year3

hello roll1307002


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

and gpa value is not updated in result value..why value of tt showing too long ...help please..thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately the script at the link provided does not run as-is. Please review (e.g. add missing ";" to end statements, don't try to create a unique constraint on a primary key column, inserting fk values with no parent...)

Comment: Can you copy and paste your code here.